# How do I add c++ code and access it in an old c-code Makefile project and compile with Netbeans

Tags: c++, c, makefile, compiler-errors, netbeans-7

I have an old C-project that was born during the 80th and imported into in NetBeans 7.2.running on OpenSuse 12.3

I want to update the project with some functionality written in c++.
That is I have some classes to use in the c project using std::string a.s.o.

Is it possible to simply add c++ files and mix-compile the project with gcc and g++?
How do I get it to work?
Below is where I am right now...

Sofar I've added in the local.h where all declarations are

```
extern "C" { #include "McaHelper.h"}
```

this line give a compile error:

```
In file included from mca.c:111:0:
local.h:49:8: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before string constantIn file included from McaHelper.h:13:0,
             from local.h:50,
             from mca.c:111:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/string:40:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: File is folder or doesn't exist
```

In the makefile, added the .o and .cpp files as + below

```
McaHelper.o: McaHelper.cpp McaHelper.h
     g++ -c McaHelper.cpp
```

But somehow this doesn't produce an .o file anywhere?

Finally I try to instanciate the class McaHelper in main(..). 
In Netbeans I find using Ctrl + spacebar, and the class .h file by pressing Ctrl + "McaHelper" (it jumps into the McaHelper.h file).

Any help appreciated

Comment: If you add C++, `main()` should be compiled with a C++ compiler as well. And the whole program linked with a C++ linker.

Comment: OK,so what you are saying is that I should compile my main with g++ instead of gcc. Will that work for the rest of the c code then, caus there are some very specific c twists in there.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/mixingcandcpluspluscode-305840.html

Comment: tryed to g++ compile, changed $(CC) in the makefile to use g++ with lots of errors as a result 
mca.o: mca.c
#$(CC) 
 g++ -c $(CFLAGS) $(DFLAGS) mca.c

Comment: StoryTeller, your link was great!, put it up as the answer if you like. Lots of goodies in there ;) thks - my answer is partly under "Accessing C++ Classes from C"

Have you got some equal link for the Makefile?

Comment: I'm glad it was of help, but I'm afraid simply putting the link up doesn't make for a good answer since it isn't very clear what was your problem from the question itself. You can post your solution yourself, in reference to the link. It will be a useful bit of information for posterity. Then just mark your answer as the accepted one to close the issue.

Comment: I haven't got it to compile just yet, but will do as u suggest - add my answer when I got it